# How does Javascript enqueue a new message when there are still things to do on the stack

Tags: javascript, node.js

Javascript is said to be single-threaded. Let's assume there is currently some CPU-intensive function on the stack:

```
function calculatePi(decimalPlaces) {
  // Currently there is calatePi(10000000) on the stack, 
  // which computes for 10 seconds.
}
```

Now some other event arrives, for example a user clicks a button or a HTTP-response is available, which results in enqueuing a new message with the associated callback in the message queue.

How does a Javascript engine enqueue this message in the message queue while there are still things to do on the stack?

If it can do that, it would mean the engine is not single-threaded. If it cannot do that, the second event would be lost.

Comment: *"Javascript is said to be single-threaded"* Not by anyone who knows what they're talking about.

Comment: Of course, the _engine_ is not single-threaded, but there's only one thread that runs your javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is executed sequentially in the event loop (like on a single thread).

No one ever said that the engine, which manages the event queue, would have to be single-threaded.

Comment: …and even then, it's possible to do multiple things concurrently in a single thread, nothing prevents the engine from stopping the JS execution when there are other things to do.